# Laravel Eloquent: how to filter multiple and/or criteria single table

Tags: php, database, laravel, filter, eloquent

I am making a real estate related app and I've been having a hard time figuring out how to set up the query so that it would return "Only Apartments or Duplexes within selected areas"  I'd like to user to be able to find multiple types of property in multiple selected quadrants of the city.

I have a database with a column "type" which is either "Apartment", "House", "Duplex", "Mobile"

In another column I have quadrant_main with values: "NW", "SW", "NE", "SE".

My code works when there is only 1 quadrant selected, but when I select multiple quadrants, I seem to get results which includes ALL the property types from the second or third or 4th quadrant, instead of only "Apartment" and "Duplex" or whatever types the user selects... Any help will be appreciated! thx in advance.

My controller function looks like this:

```
public function quadrants()
{
    $input = \Request::all();
    $currentPage = null;
    $column = "price";
    $order = "desc";

    //
    //  Looks like the input is like 0 => { key: value } ...
    //  (an Array of key/value pairs)

    $q = Listing::where('status','=','Active')->where(function($query) {
        $input = \Request::all();
        $currentPage = null;
        $typeCount = 0;
        $quadrantCount = 0;

        foreach( $input as $index => $object ) {

            $tempObj = json_decode($object);
            $key = key((array)$tempObj);
            $val = current((array)$tempObj);

            if ( $key == "type" ) {
                if ( $typeCount > 0 ) {
                    $query->orWhere('type', '=', $val );
                }
                else {
                    $query->where('type', '=', $val );
                    $typeCount++;
                }
            }
            if ( $key == "quadrant_main" ) {
                if ( $quadrantCount > 0 ) {
                    $query->orWhere('quadrant_main', '=', $val );
                }
                else {
                    $query->where('quadrant_main', '=', $val );
                    $quadrantCount++;
                }
            }
            // else {
            //  $query->orWhere($key,$val);
            // }
        }

        if( $currentPage ) {
            //Force Current Page to Page of Val
            Paginator::currentPageResolver(function() use ($currentPage) {
                return $currentPage;
            });
        }
    });

    $listings = $q->paginate(10);

    return $listings;
```

Answer (score 1):

Looking at your question, its a bit confusing and not much is given to answer definitely. Probable causes of your troubles may be bad data in database, or maybe corrupted input by user.

> Disclaimer: Please note that chances are my answer will not work for you at all.
>   In that case please provide more information and we will work things
>   out.

There is one thing that I think you have overlooked and thus you are getting awry results. First let me assume a few things.

I think a sample user input should look like this:

```
array(
    0: '{type: Apartment}',
    1: '{type: Duplex}',
    2: '{quadrant_main: NW}',
    3: '{quadrant_main: SW}',
)
```

What the user meant was give me any apartment or duplex which belongs in NW or SW region.

So after your loop is over, the final SQL statement should be something like this:

> Oh and while we are at SQL topic, you can also log the actual
>   generated SQL query in laravel so you can actually see what was the
>   final SQL getting generated. If you can post it here, it would help a
>   lot. [Look here.](http://laravel-tricks.com/tricks/display-all-sql-executed-in-eloquent)

```
select * from listings where status = 'Active' and (type = 'Apartment' or type = 'Duplex' and quadrant_main = 'NW' or quadrant_main = 'SW');
```

What this query will actually produce is this:

```
Select any listing which is active and:
1. Type is an apartment, or,
2. Type is a duplex, or,
3. Quadrant is SW, and,
4. Quadrant is NW
```

So assuming you have a database like this:

```
id|type|quadrant_main
=====================
1|Apartment|NW
2|Apartment|SW
3|Apartment|NE
4|Apartment|SE
5|Duplex|NW
6|Duplex|SW
7|Duplex|NE
8|Duplex|SE
9|House|NW
10|House|SW
11|House|NE
12|House|SE
```

You will only receive `1, and 5` in the result set. This result set is obviously wrong, plus it is depended on `NW` because that was the `and` condition.

The correct SQL query would be:

```
select * from listings where status = 'Active' and (type = 'Apartment' or type = 'Duplex') and (quadrant_main = 'NW' or quadrant_main = 'SW');
```

So structure your L5 app such that it produces this kind of SQL query. Instead of trying to cram everything in one loop, have two loops. One loop should only handle `type` and another loop should only handle `quadrant_main`. This way you will have the necessary `and` condition in the right places.

---

## As a side note:

1. Never directly use user input. Always sanitize it first.
2. Its not a best practice to put all your logic in the controller. Use repository pattern. [See here.](https://bosnadev.com/2015/03/07/using-repository-pattern-in-laravel-5/)
3. Multiple where clauses are generally applied via `Criteria`. Check that out in the above linked repository pattern.
4. You code logic is very complicated and utterly un-necessary. Instead of sending JSON objects, simply send the state of checkboxes. Don't try to generalize the function by going in loop. Instead handle all checkboxes one by one i.e. is "Apartments" selected, if yes, add that to your clause, if not, don't add.